# "Error: Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number." using cryptojs in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, cryptojs, jsr223

I am using crypto-js-4.0.0 in jmeter on a JSR223 preprocessor (javascript ECMAScript 262 Edition 5.1):

```
load('C:/Users/hlopezgu/Downloads/crypto-js-4.0.0/crypto-js.js');

var key = 'secret key 123';
var textToEncrypt = '123456';
var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(textToEncrypt, key).toString();

log.info("Texto cifrado: " + encryptedText);
```

I get the following response:

```
Error: Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number
```

I need to use this library in jmeter to encrypt data from a json and be able to send it as POST to a web service

Comment: Check whether this is related to CryptoJS [issue #256](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/256).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to run JavaScript in JMeter which is not recommended because:

1. [Nashorn engine has been removed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) from OpenJDK 15 and onwards so your solution won't be future proof.
2. Your code will be interpreted each time and cryptographic operations are quite "heavy" so [it's recommended to use Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter).

So I would recommend coming up with a proper secret key (which cannot be 14 bytes), checking out the algorithm and re-implementing it in Groovy. See [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) article for more details.

Comment: I used Cryptojs version 3.1.9 and it worked!! apparently that version is compatible with jmeter or something similar.